# Copy S3 bucket contents to another bucket using Python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So for someone looking for a fully functional code that you may be looking for. Copy and run the below snippet and change the bucket names [bucketab]&[bucketbc1] to your source and destination bucket respectively.
While you may have come across a lot of solution here in StackOverflow but none seems to be giving correct solutions and after a lot of thinking ,I got my own code working with missing attributes that should have been used with other answers provided else wher

````
import boto3
s3_resource = boto3.client('s3')
keys=[]
for obj in s3_resource.list_objects_v2(Bucket='bucketab')['Contents']:
    keys.append(obj['Key'])

#Using Boto3 Resource to do the copy
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
for key in keys:
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': 'bucketab',
        'Key': key
    }
    bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('bucketbc1')
    bucket.copy(copy_source, key)    
    ```
````

Comment: The above posted is a solution than a question to the forum.

Comment: To avoid the max 1000 object issue that you have right now (caused by calling the client `list_objects_v2` method), you could use an S3 [resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket) for the source bucket and get all objects via the [objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.objects) collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3
s3_resource = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = s3_resource.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket='bucketab')
keys=[]
for page in page_iterator:
    for i in page['Contents']:
        keys.append(i['Key'])
#Using Boto3 Resource to do the copy
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
for key in keys:
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': 'bucketab',
        'Key': key
    }
    bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('bucketbc1')
    bucket.copy(copy_source, key)
```

Comment: Also, the IAM credentials used must have both `GetObject` permission on the source bucket and `PutObject` permission on the destination bucket.

Comment: Without use of a paginator, this will only copy the first 1000 objects in a bucket.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).